# whick geckodriver is stable with firefox 51.01

Tags: firefox, automation, geckodriver

I am getting this error (Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.) in firefox.
I am using firefox 51.01.
When I don't close my browser is doesn't give error only when I close my browser it gives me error.

Comment: I am doing automation using selenium 2.53.1 and all test runs fine in chrome but ff giving me hardtime

Comment: If you are using geckodriver (most recent is 0.15.0), you should upgrade to selenium 3.3.x per the documentation at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.  That might help.  YMMV.